# Understanding coordinate vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

Let's consider a vector space *V* with $\dim(V)=3$. By taking the basis S = ($\vec{i}, \vec{j}, \vec{k}$) with $\vec{i}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ , $\vec{j} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\vec{k} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$, we can express the vector $\vec{v} = 2\vec{i}+2\vec{j}+2\vec{k}$ in the $S$ basis as: $\vec{v}_S= \begin{bmatrix}2\\2\\2\end{bmatrix}$

However, if we set the basis $S'$ = ($2\vec{i}, 2\vec{j}, 2\vec{k}$), the coordinate vector of $\vec{v}$ relative to the basis $S'$ will be:
$\vec{v}_{S'} = \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$.

I am not sure to understand, tell me if I am wrong: Coordinate vectors can be different even if they are coordinate vectors of a same vector? And on the other way, can coordinate vectors be the same even if they're coordinate vectors of different two vectors? Do they just depend on basis, not the vector's physical value?

Comment: The representations of the vector $\mathbf v$ with respect to $S$ and $S'$, respectively, are correct. Note that you do not need the explicit representation of $\mathbf i, \mathbf j, \mathbf k$ for this.

Comment: Coordinate vectors are always with respect to a basis, and if you change the basis, even just by scaling it by a factor of $2$, this will be reflected in the coordinate representation of the vector $\mathbf v$. Note that in practice (e.g. physics), you usually use the standard orthonormal basis, and do not give it much more thought.

Comment: The fact that you give the basis vectors $\mathbf i, \mathbf j, \mathbf k$ coordinates too is not really necessary, and might add to the confusion. Almost by definition, the first basis vector will be $[1, 0,\ldots]$ _with respect to the very same basis_, and analogously for the other basis vectors. The only time this becomes non-trivial is when you express the basis vectors in coordinates w.r.t. _another_ basis, i.e. you change between coordinates.